# AppStore Distribution ipa not installing after ios7 upgrade

Tags: ios7, ipa, ios-provisioning

Few days back I had everything working with a provisioning profile for Distribution( App Store).And after upgrading iphone to IOS7 the ipa not installing in any of ios7 but is working fine with ios6.

While using iTunes it says waiting... or installing... for long but when used iphone configuration Uitility it says invalid profile(Doubt is how is it working on IOS6)????

It is also working with Distribution Certificate of type ADHOC where i added the device udid in the device List.So Architecture is definitely not the problem

Answer (score 1):

Have you updated architectures for new device in your build setting.
it happens because of architecture,ipa will install on those devices which supports the cpu architecture mention in your build setting,but not on those devices who's architecture is not mentioned.

[image]

Comment: No thats not the answer...Coz with my same ARm..i just changed my distribution to adhoc and added  my client's device UDID and it worked..My qn was why in App store distribution i am not able to install builds in some IOS versions..And some it is working..With ADHOC build it is working for all